# Sort NSArray by NSDate, today

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsdate

I have loaded item from core data in an NSMutableArray. Each item, when created, is given a due date, that the user choices.

How do I sort, so only the item that is due today is displayed?

Here is what I got so far:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"dueDate == %@", [NSDate date]];

[allObjectsArray filterUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

This code doesn't work however.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 12):

How about you just calculate today at 00:00 and then tomorrow at 00:00 and then compare the dates in the predicate to those (>= and <). So all date objects must be within those two dates to be classed as being 'Today'. This requires you to only calculate 2 dates initially, no matter how many date objects are in your array.

```
// Setup
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

// Get todays year month and day, ignoring the time
NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:now];

// Components to add 1 day
NSDateComponents *oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
oneDay.day = 1;

// From date  & To date
NSDate *fromDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comp]; // Today at midnight
NSDate *toDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:oneDay toDate:fromDate options:0]; // Tomorrow at midnight

// Cleanup
[oneDay release]

// Filter Mutable Array to Today
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dueDate >= %@ && dueDate < %@", fromDate, toDate];
NSArray *filteredArray = [allObjectsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

// Job Done!
```

Comment: +1 this is probably your best option.  An alternative to `>= && <` is to use the `BETWEEN` keyword:  `NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dueDate BETWEEN %@", [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fromDate, toDate, nil]];`  (Notice that you don't have to construct a `predicateString` object when using `predicateWithFormat:`)

Comment: Thanks for the +1! Yes I thought about using the `BETWEEN` keyword, however as the toDate is the next day at midnight then I wanted the predicate to be less than but not equal to that date. If I remember correctly the `BETWEEN` is inclusive of the upper and lower bounds. Also you're quite right about the `predicateWithFormat:`!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using predicates is that if they use standard date comparison, it'll only return dates that are exactly the date *and* time of the given date. If you want "today" dates, you'll need to add a -isToday method somewhere (possible as an extension to NSDate), like this:

```
-(BOOL)dateIsToday:(NSDate *)aDate {

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit 
                                         fromDate:now];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit 
                                          fromDate:aDate];

    return (([nowComponents day] == [dateComponents day]) &&
        ([nowComponents month] == [dateComponents month]) && 
        ([nowComponents year] == [dateComponents year]));

}
```

Once you have that, it's simple enough to find the ones that are today:

```
NSMutableArray *itemsDueToday = [NSMutableArray array];

for (MyItem *item in items) {
    if ([self dateIsToday:[item date]) {
        [itemsDueToday addObject:item];
    }
}

// Done!
```

Comment: This approach would work, however it requires a lot of date processing and calculation per item. So if there were a few hundred items (or more) then the processing time would start to add up.

Comment: And on top of that there is an extra cost to be aware of:
http://www.mikeabdullah.net/NSCalendar_currentCalendar.html

Answer (score 0):

The method `-filterUsingPredicate:` only works on mutable arrays (of type `NSMutableArray`).

Try using the `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method, instead:

```
NSString *formattedPredicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dueDate == '%@'", [NSDate date]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:formattedPredicateString];
NSArray *filteredArray = [allObjectsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```